# webkit-overflow-scrolling makes element disappear

Tags: ios, css, google-chrome, webkit, smooth-scrolling

I have an app / site where I'm using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to make the scrolling smooth on iOS.

However, recently it started causing my navbar disappear upon initial load (using iOS) and it only appears when certain elements were scrolled up or down, it makes the navbar completely unusable.

If I comment out the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` then it works perfectly but the momentum scrolling is gone. I've tried adding a `z-index` hack to the navbar to make sure it's loading on top of everything, I've added a few different `display` properties as well to see if I could hack the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`, I've even tried adding the items into memory using `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);`, and nothing is working. The navbar still disappears / glitches out no matter what when `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` is included.

Has anyone had this glitch before and figured it out? I really don't want to load an entire JS library just to handle my scrolling, but I might have to if I can't figure this glitch out. The non-momentum scrolling feels so clunky and unusable.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I had a list of items with `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` that were not showing as soon as I enabled `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`. My problem was that I had the elements with `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` nested inside another div.

In other words, there was a div in between the one with the overflow-scrolling: touch and the children with the translate3d. Didn't realize they had to be direct children.

Once I consolidated my divs directly it stopped hiding the elements and worked perfectly. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case I was trying to use `::before` to display an overlay. I worked on Chrome, but not in Safari/iPhone. I end up not using it in the end, I replace it with `::after`