# Overlay without using the a relative parent and filling child

Tags: html, css

Consider the following example that renders a semi-transparent red layer onto some text.

```html
<div style="position: relative">
  <p>
    Foo
  </p>
  <p>
    Bar
  </p>
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5)">
  </div>
</div>
```

There are some issues on iOS Safari that makes using relative-divs in scrolling areas flaky.

So, is there a way to achieve the same effect of overlaying without using relative divs? CSS only, no JavaScript!

EDIT:

The actual effect I want to achieve is to change the overlay into a different color when the mouse hovers.

EDIT:

Looks like the "flakiness" is still present in current iOS versions. Here are some OLDER references to similar problems:

- [Elements disappear when scrolling in Safari - -webkit-transform fix only works the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50105780/elements-disappear-when-scrolling-in-safari-webkit-transform-fix-only-works-t)
- https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/8
- [webkit-overflow-scrolling makes element disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585040/webkit-overflow-scrolling-makes-element-disappear)
- [iPad Safari scrolling causes HTML elements to disappear and reappear with a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807620/ipad-safari-scrolling-causes-html-elements-to-disappear-and-reappear-with-a-dela)
- [iPad Safari elements disappear and reappear with a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621432/ipad-safari-elements-disappear-and-reappear-with-a-delay)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the background on the main element and make the child element behind.

```css
.box {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.box>* {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.box:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>
    Foo
  </p>
  <p>
    Bar
  </p>
</div>
```

Simply make sure there is no property used on the main element that will create a stacking context. Related: [Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)

Comment: Looks great. The child is using relative, let's see if I still see the flakiness in iOS Safari with this approach.

Comment: I added a remark about hovering to my question. Could you please amend your answer and add ".box:hover {background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);}" to it. That shows the effect and works perfectly! Many thanks!

Comment: I now carefully checked on iOS Safari. The elements still randomly disappear as soon I introduce "relative" somewhere in the tree...